# timeout causes while read loop to end when `cat` is timed out

Tags: shell-script, cat, function, readline, timeout

I am unable to discern why `timeout` in a function call will cause a loop to stop.  I have a "solution", but I am really very intrigued as to how / why this is happening!  It seems to be something to do with `cat` being the command getting timed out?

TL;DR

`while read -r line; do ... done < file` gets terminated when a `timeout` occurs on `cat`, producing the wrong output and exit code.  The loop does **not** loop through every line in the file.

If instead an array is created first of all lines in the file, and then `...` is executed in a `for line in "${all_lines[@]}"; do`, all lines are processed and the output of `timeout` with respect to exit codes is correct.

---

Suppose the script `grade.sh` intends to read all of `tests.txt` and execute `soln.sh`, making sure that `soln.sh` terminates.  To demonstrate a "working" example, `soln.sh` will first `sleep`.

#### `tests.txt`

```
first
second
third
fourth
fifth
```

#### `grade.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r line; do
    echo "Test: $line"
    output="$(timeout 2 ./soln.sh "$line")"
    timed_exit=$?
    echo "  Soln Output: $output"
    echo "  Timed exit:  $timed_exit"
done < "tests.txt"
```

#### `soln.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ "$1" == "third" ]]; then
    sleep 3
fi
echo "[soln running $1]"
```

#### expected output

```
Test: first
  Soln Output: [soln running first]
  Timed exit:  0
Test: second
  Soln Output: [soln running second]
  Timed exit:  0
Test: third
  Soln Output: 
  Timed exit:  124
Test: fourth
  Soln Output: [soln running fourth]
  Timed exit:  0
Test: fifth
  Soln Output: [soln running fifth]
  Timed exit:  0
```

---

If we change `soln` to do something that will continue forever (waiting for input), the loop ends instead

#### `soln.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ "$1" == "third" ]]; then
    cat $(find . -name iamnothere.txt) | wc -l
fi
echo "[soln running $1]"
```

#### output terminates early, extra `2`, wrong `exit` code

```
Test: first
  Soln Output: [soln running first]
  Timed exit:  0
Test: second
  Soln Output: [soln running second]
  Timed exit:  0
Test: third
  Soln Output: 2
[soln running third]
  Timed exit:  0
```

---

Hacky fix is to loop through every line first and use a `for` loop which will bypass this.

#### "fixed" `grade.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

all_lines=()
idx=0
while read -r line; do
    all_lines[idx]="$line"
    (( idx++ ))
done < "tests.txt"

for line in "${all_lines[@]}"; do
    echo "Test: $line"
    output="$(timeout 2 ./soln.sh "$line")"
    timed_exit=$?
    echo "  Soln Output: $output"
    echo "  Timed exit:  $timed_exit"
done
```

#### expected output

```
Test: first
  Soln Output: [soln running first]
  Timed exit:  0
Test: second
  Soln Output: [soln running second]
  Timed exit:  0
Test: third
  Soln Output: 
  Timed exit:  124
Test: fourth
  Soln Output: [soln running fourth]
  Timed exit:  0
Test: fifth
  Soln Output: [soln running fifth]
  Timed exit:  0
```

#### is this a feature or a bug or am I missing something?

It seems to me like `cat` is somehow overriding `timeout`, since the rest of the script gets to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 cat $(find . -name iamnothere.txt) | wc -l
```

assuming that `iamnothere.txt` does not exist becomes

```
cat | wc -l
```

which consumes standard input, [the same standard input that the `while` loop is reading the lines from](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66154/ssh-causes-while-loop-to-stop). `for` avoids this by not using standard input like `while` does. This can be observed by using a bare `cat` for the second line case, as this shows that the third line has been read by that `cat`:

```
$ cat lines 
first
secon
third
$ cat looper 
#!/bin/sh
while read line; do
    x=$(timeout 2 ./doer "$line")
    echo "$line out=$x code=$?"
done < lines

$ cat doer 
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = secon ]; then
    cat
else
    echo "$1 pid$$"
fi

$ ./looper 
first out=first pid42079 code=0
secon out=third code=0
$
```

Comment: Wow thank you for explaining, I was aware that subshells are not completely new processes, but I had no idea they inherited `stdin`!  If anybody else is reading this, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38133590/3814202) gives a good explanation of how it works in addition to what @thrig linked to in their answer.

Comment: Not only is it inherited, the processes both point to the same underlying object. If stdin is seekable, a seek by one process will affect where the other subsequently reads from.