# ssh kills "while read"

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a really confusing error, in the following script. `reservations` is just a file with 100 lines, let's say something like this:

```
apple
pear
fruit
...
```

```
cat reservations | while read LINE;
do
  echo $LINE
  for i in {0..2}; do
    ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 admin@render rm -rf /tmp/lock$i
    echo $i
  done
done
```

(This is already a simplified version of a production script.)

Now, what I would have expected, is to see an output like this:

```
apple
0
1
2
pear
0
1
2
...
```

BUT, I only get the first line, i.e., the output is

```
apple
0
1
2
```

If I remove the `ssh`, everything works! For some reason, the `ssh` messes up the whole thing, and exits the while loop. I have absolutely no idea why that is!!

Comment: Does it really exit the while loop or does it exit the whole script? Or maybe does the script hang? Do you have `set -e` somewhere in your script? Can you reproduce the problem with the simplified script? Or did you manually "convert" your real script and its output to the simplified version? BTW: Instead of `cat reservations | while read LINE; do ... done` you can use `while read LINE; do ... done < reservations`

Comment: @Bodo What's shown above is the whole script, I have no `set -e`. The simplified version reproduces. I tried the `<reservations` thing but it didn't help

Comment: Can you have further details on your ssh command with increased verbosity : `ssh -v` (more `v`'s (up to 3) for even more verbosity)

Comment: [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66154/ssh-causes-while-loop-to-stop?rq=1) solves it. Should I remove my question? Thing is, googling didn't help because there is no "kill" there.

Comment: Hi, next time you should add above comment as answer and mark it as a solving answer. I almost miss this little comments :) .. thanks for thinking like me when state an issue haha "kills"